# How does flatten behave diffrently with Vec<Vec<_>> and Vec<Result<T<E>> or Vec<Option<T>> in rust

Tags: rust, iterator, flatten, rust-clippy

The official docs of [iter::flatten](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Flatten.html) states :

> An iterator that flattens one level of nesting in an iterator of things that can be turned into iterators.

But for this code:

```rust
if let Ok(entries) = fs::read_dir("/path/to/dir") {
        for entry in entries {
            if let Ok(entry) = entry {
                // Do something
            }
        }
}
```

Clippy suggests to use `entries.flatten()` instead of `if-let` block, But here "nesting" is not there, instead it's an Iterator of Results. "Nesting" would look like an Iterator of Iterators.

There's no exclusive `flatten()` method implementation in [ReadDir](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.ReadDir.html) which is returned by `fs::read_dir()`

So my question is what exactly flatten do here? How does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But here "nesting" is not there, instead it's an Iterator of Results

Ah, but [`Result` implements `IntoIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#impl-IntoIterator-for-Result%3CT%2C%20E%3E).  This means you do effectively have nested iterators... or rather, nested items *that can be turned into an iterator* which is all the bound on [`Iterator::flatten()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flatten) requires of an iterator's items:

```
where Self::Item: IntoIterator
```

The implementation for `Result<T, E>` yields the contained `T` when `Ok` and yields no items when `Err`.  Therefore, clippy is correct -- you can use `Iterator::flatten` to simplify this code.

And the same is true for `Option<T>`.  When converted to an iterator, it will yield the contained `T` when `Some` and no items when `None`.

Answer (score 0):

[`Result` also implements `IntoIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.68.2/src/core/result.rs.html#1835), with an iterator that yields one element in the `Ok` case and nothing in the `Err` case, so it works.

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is what exactly flatten do here? How does it work?

```rust
fn flatten(self) -> Flatten<Self> where
    Self: Sized,
    Self::Item: IntoIterator
```

So flatten "chains" the items of the subject iterator if they are iterable (`IntoIterator`).

`Result` and `Option` implement `IntoIterator`, behaving as iterators of 0..=1 elements (depending whether the result/option has a value or a none/error).

So it just replaces the Result by its item (`Ok`) if there is one, otherwise it's stripped. Which is essentially what you're doing here, hence the recommendation of clippy.